# converting date formate with moment

Tags: momentjs

This Meteor server code needs to get "06 2008" from "Fri Jun 06 00:00:00 BST 2008" but I am getting "Invalid date", Any ideas? Thanks

```js
  let dat = new Date('Fri Jun 06 00:00:00 BST 2008');
  let mDat = moment(dat).format("dd yyyy");
  console.log(mDat);
```

Comment: how/where do you getting 'Fri Jun 06 00:00:00 BST 2008' this?

Comment: you can try this var a = new moment('Fri Jun 06 00:00:00 BST 2008','ddd MMM DD hh:mm:ss Z YYYY');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it Doesn't recognize your Time Standard.. so remove and try .. if you want date use **DD** for year use **YYYY** its case sensitive

```js
let dat = new Date('Fri Jun 06 00:00:00 2008');
let mDat = moment(dat).format("DD YYYY");
console.log(mDat);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple solution-
(JS BIN link - https://jsbin.com/nihoxivoxa/edit?js,console)

```js
var date_text = 'Fri Jun 06 00:00:00 BST 2008';
var date_text = date_text.split('BST').join();
var dat = new Date(date_text);
var mDat = moment(dat).format("DD YYYY");
 console.log(mDat);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1/scriptaculous.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```